# Why does axios delete not work as I want, how to fix it?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I took the data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, I got it out normally, but I also want to create a button when I click on it, the post will be deleted. I wrote the code, but it does not work, can you tell me what is the error? When you click on the button in the console writes 'delete', but the post remains.

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x3ec.png)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post of posts">
        <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
        <button  @click="deleteData(post._id)">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return{
      posts: [],
    }
  },

    created(){
      axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
      })
    },
    methods: {
        deleteData(_id) {
          axios.delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log('delete')
                        this.posts.splice(
                          this.posts.findIndex(e => e.id === id)
                        )
                      })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                  },
                }
              }
</script>
```

Comment: `_id` vs `id` I guess?

Comment: You were right, but when I changed _id everywhere on id, now when I click, for example, on the second element in the list, the second element of the list is deleted and all the list elements that appear after the second element are left with the first element, what to do in in this case?

Comment: can you make a `codepen` or `jsfiddle` illustrating what your issue is? I'm actually not following

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good, but you're using methods in wrong way.

There are two things you have to remember.

> First, your post variable is an array.

API gives you json data, and what you have to do is to `push` that data into your array, instead of using `= operand`

> Secondly, `splice(index)` just returns the same object.

Using `splice(index, 1)` instead.

It will delete 1 post from that index.